# How to catch error in FILE IO using C?

Tags: c, io, large-files

I am using following code snippet in C to copy a file:

```
#define CHUNK 4096 
char buf[CHUNK];
FILE *file , *out;
size_t nread;

file = fopen("test", "rb");
out = fopen("out", "wb");

if (file) {
    while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file)) > 0)
        fwrite(buf, 1, nread, out);
    if (ferror(file)) {
        /* Not getting error here */
    }
    fclose(file);
    fclose(out);
}
```

My file is very large (200 MB), I have to handle errors if file is moved or removed while reading, writing is in progress. How can I do that?

Let me clear it tad more, Any how I will get access to path by some wifi means. So if wifi will be disconnected then how I'll get the error..

Comment: shouldn't the OS layer take of this? as long as a process exist and uses file access, the os internally keeps track of it, although if it gets e.g. moved? I think linux does that.

Comment: You're using Windows, right? Could you use one of the "sharing" file operations? Check out, for instance, [_sopen_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w64k0ytk.aspx).

Comment: I am using linux platform, While the process is going on I delete file using this `sudo rm -f test`  now there is no even lock file, but still getting proper output.

Comment: because the real deletion of the file happens when the last process releases its file handle to it. if you delete it during the process, it gets hidden but still exists. so `ls` won't show it but its actually still there.

Comment: can you explain why you want to detect this? You might want to read about [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) and check the status of the file during writing. you might also be interested in [inotify](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/).

Comment: @Bort `ls -a` shows hidden files, thanks for sharing info about inotify.

Comment: sorry for the confusion (since english isn't my first language), I don't mean hidden files in the sense of `.dotfile` rather than no longer accessible for any other process.

Answer (score 2):

If the count bytes written is different from the `nread` parameter this would indicate an error, so:

```
if (fwrite(buf, 1, nread, out) != nread) {
  // error handling
}
```

Under windows you could lock the file using `_lock_file();` to prevent other processes from deleting the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

if (file) {
   // lock file
   _lock_file(file);

   while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, file)) > 0)
      fwrite(buf, 1, nread, out);

      // unlock and close the file
      _unlock_file(file);
      fclose(file);
      fclose(out);
}
```

Comment: although your answer is write, but chances are least to not get proper data if we open in binary mode, till yet I haven't get that error. But my scenario is different, the loop goes on and file output file is properly written.

Comment: @Yuvi - I updated my answer. *EDIT* Sorry I didn't realized you were running linux.

Comment: What if while reading 'fread' file get missing.. then how can I got to know that....

Answer (score 0):

You should probably open your output file in write mode, i.e. `"wb"`.

How to handle errors: check return values of the I/O functions, and try to deal with the errors. You can use `feof()` and `ferror()` to analyze what went wrong. Make sure to always do some I/O before calling either of them (don't try to detemine EOF before reading).

Comment: Sorry, it is in "wb" mode only, it was a typo mistak